# How to remove blue line from image background

Tags: css

I have very simple code for email newsletter share icons. My problem is there is an background blue near the image. I removed outline and border using css for both image and anchor tag. But I am out of luck.
Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/o70cd4g8/

My code:

```
<table align="center" width="500">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <div align="right" style="padding-right:0px">
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img border="0" style="border:0" src="https://s-passets-ec.pinimg.com/images/about/buttons/small-p-button.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" alt="Follow Me on Pinterest" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://www.seattleu.edu/uploadedImages/MarCom/youtube_16px.png" alt="youtube" title="youtube" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://www.nextbyte.com.ar/images/social/Twitter-16px.gif" alt="twitter" title="twitter" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://sfcv.org/sites/files/images/facebook-16px.png" alt="facebook" title="facebook" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://perishablepress.com/wp/wp-content/images/2006/feed-collection/feed-icon_orange-16px+.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `a {text-decoration: none;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/10nwa0Le/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `text-decoration: none`

```
table > tbody > tr > td > div > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
table > tbody > tr > td > div > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="500">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <div align="right" style="padding-right:0px"> <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img border="0" style="border:0" src="https://s-passets-ec.pinimg.com/images/about/buttons/small-p-button.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" alt="Follow Me on Pinterest" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
 <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://www.seattleu.edu/uploadedImages/MarCom/youtube_16px.png" alt="youtube" title="youtube" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
 <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://www.nextbyte.com.ar/images/social/Twitter-16px.gif" alt="twitter" title="twitter" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
 <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://sfcv.org/sites/files/images/facebook-16px.png" alt="facebook" title="facebook" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>
 <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <img height="16" width="16" border="0" style="border:0" align="absmiddle" src="http://perishablepress.com/wp/wp-content/images/2006/feed-collection/feed-icon_orange-16px+.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS" class="CToWUd">
                    </a>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Reason: text-decoration: underline; is applied to  tag by default
>   browser stylesheet, so if you want to over ride it or if you want that
>   none of the  tags on your website should have an underline than
>   simply use this

Answer (score 2):

its anchor `text-decoration`

```
a{
        text-decoration:none;        
    }
```

or better add some class to those anchors and target them from that classname

Comment: I am using this code for newsletter. So I did the changes inline. Thank you